# Change prices based on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery

im currently looking for help in this matter. 
The problem here is that instead of  doing the checkbox value + the previous value it is adding it all together like placing "10" and after other checkbox click it adds the value to it and does not count it like "1020" instead of doing 10+20

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(
      function() {
        total = total + parseInt($(this).val());

      });
    var input = document.getElementById("valor");
    input.value += input.value + total;

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Comissões Técnicas</label>
<label class="container newlabel">CPT
                          <input type="checkbox"  value="10"  name="cpt" >
                          <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label><br>
<label class="container newlabel">CPGA (Gratuito para Sócios da SPG)
                          <input type="checkbox"  value="10"  name="cpga" >
                          <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label><br>
<input id="valor" type="text">
```

Comment: when you are using `input.value += input.value + total;`, you sum string `input.value`, another string `input.value` and get "10" + "10" + 10 that will return you string `101010` you should use `input.value = +input.value + total;` here you will get `input.value=` number `input.value` plus number `total` and will return 20

Answer (score 1):

Check if `repeatedly` `click` on checkbox should be handled also on `uncheck` score should reduced.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      
      $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
          var total = 0;
          total = parseInt(document.getElementById("valor").value);
          if(isNaN(total)){
            total = 0;
          }
          if($(this).prop('checked')){
              total = total + parseInt($(this).val());
          } else {
              total = total - parseInt($(this).val());
          };
          var input = document.getElementById("valor");
          input.value = total;
       });
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <label>Comissões Técnicas</label>
    <label class="container newlabel">CPT
                                  <input type="checkbox"  value="10"  name="cpt" >
                                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label><br>
    <label class="container newlabel">CPGA (Gratuito para Sócios da SPG)
                                  <input type="checkbox"  value="20"  name="cpga" >
                                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label><br>
    <input id="valor" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
input.value += input.value + total;
```

means (since `input.value` is a `String`), concatenate `input.value` with `total` after making sure `total` is a `String`.  Don't use the `+=` and be sure to use `parseInt()` on anything that you want to be a number.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(
      function() {
        total = total + parseInt($(this).val());

      });
    var input = document.getElementById("valor");

    /*
     * You don't need +=
     * You do need to parseInt
     * You need to make sure to handle empty String ""
     */
    input.value = (parseInt(input.value, 10) || 0) + total;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Comissões Técnicas</label>
<label class="container newlabel">CPT
  <input type="checkbox"  value="10"  name="cpt" >
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>
<label class="container newlabel">CPGA (Gratuito para Sócios da SPG)
  <input type="checkbox"  value="10"  name="cpga" >
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label><br>
<input id="valor" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me, if I don't quite understand your problem, but shouldn't you just have to change `input.value += input.value + total;` to `input.value = total;` for the required result?

Comment: Thanks  , this is the result of coding non stop for hours, the error was right in front of me and I was not even seeing... I cannot vote, as soon as I can ill +1

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jQuery and I love to user `reduce` method I can advice you this solution

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    var total = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').toArray().reduce(function(pre, post) {
      return pre + parseInt($(post).val());
    }, 0);
    $('#valor').val(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Comissões Técnicas</label>
<label class="container newlabel">CPT
                                  <input type="checkbox"  value="10"  name="cpt" >
                                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label><br>
<label class="container newlabel">CPGA (Gratuito para Sócios da SPG)
                                  <input type="checkbox"  value="20"  name="cpga" >
                                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label><br>
<input id="valor" type="text">
```

If your `value` is always a number you can use `value / 1` to convert number string into numeric type. This only if you are SURE that the number will be always a number and not a string containing number, eg. `11.jpg` is not valid.

This is a performance test for your case:
https://jsperf.com/parseint-versus-divide-by-one/1

So you can rewrite the code as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    var total = 
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').toArray().reduce(function(pre, post) {
      var val = $(post).val() / 1;
      return pre + (val ? val : 0);
    }, 0);
    $('#valor').val(total);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the new insight I managed to make my code work but was good to see a different method il sure keep it marked for later uses !

Comment: I'm glad for this, I added a different approach and a performance test for both uses.